# How to disable "s" and "S" keybindings in Paredit.vim

Tags: vim, clojurescript, paredit

the default "s" and "S" in paredit.vim override my vim-sneak plugin defaults "s" keybindings.  Do you know of a way to disable paredit.vim default keybindings?

Comment: I think you need to check vim community: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770103/overriding-a-remapping-from-a-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Open `paredit.vim` file and comment these lines by adding `"` at the beginning of each one:

```sh
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> s  :<C-U>call PareditEraseFwd()<CR>i

nnoremap <buffer> <silent> S  V:<C-U>call PareditChange(visualmode(),1)<CR>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid modifying the source.

Comment: Both scripts will be sourced so you will get only the **last mapping** for `s` or `S`. That's why you need to comment those lines in order to get the mappings of vim-sneak and ignore this one.